# Lag time series with new rows

Tags: r, xts, lag

I would like to lead/lag variable, but I don't want to lose any points.

For example:
x (xts object):

```
2017-06-30  1    
2017-07-31  2
2017-08-31  3
2017-09-30  4
2017-10-31  5
2017-11-30  6
2017-12-31  7
2018-01-31  8
2018-02-28  9
2018-03-31  10
```

When I do

```
lag(x,2)
```

I get:

```
2017-06-30  NA
2017-07-31  NA
2017-08-31  1
2017-09-30  2
2017-10-31  3
2017-11-30  4
2017-12-31  5
2018-01-31  6
2018-02-28  7
2018-03-31  8
```

I lost 9 for 2018-04-30 and 10 for 2018-05-31. Is there a way to keep them? I know it is a problem with finding additional dates (2018-04-30 and 2018-05-31), but maybe there is a way to have it done automatically.

Comment: But it goes against the definition of lagging, doesn't it? What do you want these `na` values to be instead?

Comment: No, because I use lagged variable, I can use it for example for prediction. So in this case I can have two months ahead prediction using model depended on x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhat prolix, but this does the job. This requires `dplyr` and `magrittr`.

```
# Original data frame
df <- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2017-07-01"), length=10, by="1 month") - 1, n = 1:10)

#          date  n
# 1  2017-06-30  1
# 2  2017-07-31  2
# 3  2017-08-31  3
# 4  2017-09-30  4
# 5  2017-10-31  5
# 6  2017-11-30  6
# 7  2017-12-31  7
# 8  2018-01-31  8
# 9  2018-02-28  9
# 10 2018-03-31 10
```

Next, I define the lag length:

```
# Length of lag
lag_length <- 2
```

Here, I create the extra rows to be added:

```
# Extra rows to add
extra <- data.frame(date = (seq(tail(df$date, 1) + 1, length = lag_length + 1, by = "1 month") - 1)[-1], n = NA)
```

Finally, I bind them to the original data frame and lag the variable `n`:

```
# Bind extra rows and lag 'n' by 'lag_length'
df %<>%
  bind_rows(extra) %>% 
  mutate(n = lag(n, lag_length))

# New data frame
#          date  n
# 1  2017-06-30 NA
# 2  2017-07-31 NA
# 3  2017-08-31  1
# 4  2017-09-30  2
# 5  2017-10-31  3
# 6  2017-11-30  4
# 7  2017-12-31  5
# 8  2018-01-31  6
# 9  2018-02-28  7
# 10 2018-03-31  8
# 11 2018-04-30  9
# 12 2018-05-31 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to pad your values with `NA`s while your previous values get extended to new dates, which in turn are the last days of the following months.

If so, this function using `lubridate` does exactly that:

```
dpad <- function(x,n){
  require(lubridate)

  d <- as.character(ymd(x[nrow(x),1]) + 1  + months(1:n) -1)

  return(cbind(c(x[,1],d),c(rep(NA,n),x[,2])))

}
```

In this case `x` is expected to be a 2 column object, with 1st column dates and 2nd column values. `n` specifies the number of `NA`'s appended to the beginning:

```
dpad(x, 2)

# [,1]            [,2]
# [1,] "2017-06-30" NA  
# [2,] "2017-07-31" NA  
# [3,] "2017-08-31" "1" 
# [4,] "2017-09-30" "2" 
# [5,] "2017-10-31" "3" 
# [6,] "2017-11-30" "4" 
# [7,] "2017-12-31" "5" 
# [8,] "2018-01-31" "6" 
# [9,] "2018-02-28" "7" 
# [10,] "2018-03-31" "8" 
# [11,] "2018-04-30" "9" 
# [12,] "2018-05-31" "10"
```

Comment: Do you now the way to expand date sequence automatically? Here is last day of month, but I would like to make it more universal.

Comment: @mbt I guess you would need some condition ... either it's always the last day, or it's the difference between the last two dates, or you specify it as an argument. How is it in your data? EDIT: Or you just use year-month

Comment: It is always last day now, but as I wrote, it would be nice to have it working for all cases.

Comment: @mbt as I said, you can use the year-month combination only, that would generalize it. But when you speak of other cases, can you give an example?

Comment: Using year-month combination only will cause losing information about day. By other cases I meant for example first day of month or 15th day of month. I wondering if there is a function in R that recognize a pattern in sequence and may continue it, like ther is in Excel.